# ExtJS Error : No Such Entity

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm new with ExtJS.

I want to show an edit form which need a combobox component linked to remote datastore (category datastore) like this :

```
Ext.define('AccountingApp.view.content.accAccountSubCategory.Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'accAccountSubCategoryForm',

    requires: [
        'Ext.window.Window',
    ],

    bind: {
        title: '{title}'
    },
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 430,
    closable: true,
    constrain: true,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        reference: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        border: false,
        modelValidation: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            reference: 'accaccountcategory',
            publishes: 'value',
            fieldLabel: 'Select Category',
            displayField: 'account_category',
            valueField: 'id',
            anchor: '-15',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'backend/accAccountCategory/combo',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'array',
                        rootProperty: 'data'
                    }
                },
                //the error is here
                model: 'AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory',
                autoLoad: true
            }),
            minChars: 0,
            queryParam: 'q',
            queryMode: 'remote',
        }]
    },

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: 'onSaveClick'
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: 'onCancelClick'
    }]
});
```

But, On this line :

```
model: 'AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory',
```

I got the error message :

```
Uncaught Error: No such Entity "AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory".
```

I tried to change the model to `model: 'AccAccountCategory',` but the error was same.

Can you tell me what's wrong with the code ?

Comment: Tried some trick, finally I found that we can replace `model: 'AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory',` to 

     `fields: [ 'id', 'account_category' ],`

based on our model definition.
But this solution is temporary, still waiting the best answer :).

Comment: You didn't show the most crucial part. Where did you declare the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer depends on what architecture your program uses.

First: you must require your model.

```
requires: [
    'Ext.window.Window',
    'AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory'
],
```

Second: In this pattern you must create your model with this code, as an item in the store's config:

```
model: Ext.create('AccountingApp.model.AccAccountCategory'),
```

Comment: A advice: try use Sencha cmd to build or generate your app with ExtJs MVC pattern... so easy so powerful...

Comment: work like charm. thanks..
yeah, I'm using Sencha cmd to build this app.